# Share on Facebook-dialog with ‘og:url’ does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

As of roughly April 2019 the Share to Facebook-dialog on my website http://www.trivia-web.com has stopped working. I have more than one dialog.

The dialog does not share the URL, title, description, nor image correctly.

The sharing works again if I remove the ‘og:url’ part but then when the user clicks on the image on Facebook he is not taken to the correct URL (because there is no url).

The URL I need to redirect to (the value of ‘og:url’) is never the same so I cannot hard-code that value.

Searching the web, I wasn’t able to find any meaningful information about this problem. Facebook doesn’t mention anything on their developer site.

```
var tw_url = 'http://www.trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq';
var tw_title = 'This is the title.';
var tw_descr = 'This is the description.';
var tw_img = 'http://www.trivia-web.com/img/TriviaWeb-ask-on-fb.png';


        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: {
                    'og:url': tw_url,
                    'og:title': tw_title,
                    'og:description': tw_descr,
                    'og:image': tw_img
                }
            })
        },
            function (response) {
                // Action after response
            });
```

Who do I make this work again?

Comment: Share a unique URL and put the og-tags on the page that the URL points to.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it works. If it doesn't work explain what you did and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have meta tags on my page.
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.trivia-web.com/" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="TriviaWeb" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="TriviaWeb - Play Fun Trivia" />
But I have several location where I want to share a different URL (different over time and user) and that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That way I said. You have to share a unique URL like "http://www.trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq" And on that page you have to set og:url to the same thing. If you just set it to trivia-web.com it is just going to do a redirect.

Comment: There is no page trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq. The parameter q=001232jmeq is just used to make trivia-web.com look and behave different than without parameter. Also, on trivia-web.com there are several share buttons with different URL so adding a og:url in an html meta tag would not work.

Comment: trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq is a page. When I got to it a page loads. Put the og-tag on the page that matches that URL.

Comment: Now I have <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq" />. It still does not work.

Comment: No you don't. When Facebook request that URL it sees `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.trivia-web.com/">` as you can see here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trivia-web.com%2F%3Fq%3D001232jmeq . I would suggest using the Facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trivia-web.com%2F%3Fq%3D001232jmeq

Comment: Now I get.  Object Invalid Value: Object at URL 'http://www.trivia-web.com/?q=001232jmeq' of type '' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.  Click on "Ask on Facebook".

Comment: When do you get that error?